# Render screen after JavaScript has been injected in React Native WebView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-webview

I'm using the `injectedJavaScript` prop with a React Native WebView. Currently, my screen is rendered, then the JavaScript is injected, then the screen is re-rendered.

Is there a way to render my screen **after** my JavaScript code has been injected?